# Rotating and spacing axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, boxplot

I have a plot where the x-axis is a factor whose labels are long.  While probably not an ideal visualization, for now I'd like to simply rotate these labels to be vertical.  I've figured this part out with the code below, but as you can see, the labels aren't totally visible.

```
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot")
q + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]

Comment: As ggplot 3.3.0 is out now, IMO the accepted answer should be changed to [jan-glx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60650595/3082472)s one

Answer (score 1518, accepted):

Change the last line to

```
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

By default, the axes are aligned at the center of the text, even when rotated.  When you rotate +/- 90 degrees, you usually want it to be aligned at the edge instead:

[image]

The image above is from [this blog post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/ggplot2-barplots/).

Comment: In the newest version of ggplot2 the command would be:

    `q + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 0))`

Comment: To those for whom hjust is not behaving as described here, try `theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))`. As of ggplot2 0.9.3.1 this seems to be the solution.

Comment: Actually, I had to combine the two solutions above to get correctly aligned labels: `q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))`

Comment: @jupp0r's correct. `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))` IS THE ONE WORKING CURRENTLY.

Comment: if you wanted 45° rotated labels (easier to read) `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))` gives good results

Comment: In my case I have the vjust was 0.3 to really make it look centered `q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.3, hjust=1))`. I am using `ezplot` from `ez` package, and using `vjust = 0.5` produced a slightly crooked result

Comment: In case someone is looking for it, it works also with `qplot`

Comment: How can I use it when I'm using the option geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")?  Strangely then it doesn't rotate the labels

Comment: Nowadays, you can simply use `guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90))  + `. (see also my answer below)

Comment: For better clarity on using hjust and vjust see this excellent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot/7267364#7267364

Answer (score 167):

[`ggplot 3.3.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/) fixes this by providing `guide_axis(angle = 90)` (as `guide` argument to `scale_..` or as `x` argument to `guides`):

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper", as.character(diamonds$cut))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, carat)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  # ... or, equivalently:
  # guides(x =  guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  NULL
```

[image]

From [the documentation of the `angle` argument](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_axis.html):

> Compared to setting the angle in theme() / element_text(), this also
> uses some heuristics to automatically pick the hjust and vjust that
> you probably want.

---

Alternatively, it also provides  `guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)` (as `guide` argument to `scale_..` or as `x` argument to `guides`) to overcome the over-plotting problem by dodging the labels vertically. It works quite well in this case:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))

ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, carat)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  NULL
```

[image]

Comment: Although I like the dodging solution here, it's worth noting that `guide_axis(angle=90)` picks the correct vjust and hjust values, which addresses the issue in the OP.

Comment: @eipi10 Thanks, I was not aware and now added this to the answer!

Comment: unfortunately this solution doesn't;t play well with ggplotly function as the rotated axis label is not carried over. Only the previous theme() solution works with ggplotly

Comment: @Olivier yes [plotly.R](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R)'s `ggplotly` only supports a subset of ggplot's functionality. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73635190/stagger-x-axis-labels-using-plotly-in-r) provides an workaround for dodging.

Answer (score 143):

## **Use `coord_flip()`**

```
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))

qplot(cut, carat, data = diamonds, geom = "boxplot") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

## Add `str_wrap()`

```
# wrap text to no more than 15 spaces
library(stringr)
diamonds$cut2 <- str_wrap(diamonds$cut, width = 15)
qplot(cut2, carat, data = diamonds, geom = "boxplot") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

---

In Ch 3.9 of [*R for Data Science*](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/data-visualisation.html#coordinate-systems), Wickham and Grolemund speak to this exact question:

> `coord_flip()` switches the x and y axes. This is useful (for example), if you want horizontal boxplots. It’s also useful for long labels: it’s hard to get them to fit without overlapping on the x-axis.

Answer (score 105):

To make the text on the tick labels fully visible and read in the same direction as the y-axis label, change the last line to

```
q + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

Answer (score 33):

I'd like to provide an alternate solution, a robust solution similar to what I am about to propose was required in the latest version of [ggtern](http://ggtern.com), since introducing the canvas rotation feature.

Basically, you need to determine the relative positions using trigonometry, by building a function which returns an `element_text` object, given angle (ie degrees) and positioning (ie one of x,y,top or right) information.

```
#Load Required Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

#Build Function to Return Element Text Object
rotatedAxisElementText = function(angle,position='x'){
  angle     = angle[1]; 
  position  = position[1]
  positions = list(x=0,y=90,top=180,right=270)
  if(!position %in% names(positions))
    stop(sprintf("'position' must be one of [%s]",paste(names(positions),collapse=", ")),call.=FALSE)
  if(!is.numeric(angle))
    stop("'angle' must be numeric",call.=FALSE)
  rads  = (angle - positions[[ position ]])*pi/180
  hjust = 0.5*(1 - sin(rads))
  vjust = 0.5*(1 + cos(rads))
  element_text(angle=angle,vjust=vjust,hjust=hjust)
}
```

Frankly, in my opinion, I think that an 'auto' option should be made available in `ggplot2` for the `hjust` and `vjust` arguments, when specifying the angle, anyway, lets demonstrate how the above works.

```
#Demonstrate Usage for a Variety of Rotations
df    = data.frame(x=0.5,y=0.5)
plots = lapply(seq(0,90,length.out=4),function(a){
  ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = rotatedAxisElementText(a,'x'),
          axis.text.y = rotatedAxisElementText(a,'y')) +
    labs(title = sprintf("Rotated %s",a))
})
grid.arrange(grobs=plots)
```

Which produces the following:

[image: Example]

Comment: I do not obtain the same results, for me the axis text is never well adjusted using your auto method. However, using `rads  = (-angle - positions[[ position ]])*pi/180` produced better placements. Note the additional minus sign before angle. Thanks for the code anyway :)

Comment: Get idea! I wanted to adapt your function to be able to run it with any parameters of `element_text()`. 





So I added a parameter in the function  called `element_text_params = list()` and  replaced the last line in your function by `element_text_params <- c(element_text_params, list(angle = angle, vjust = vjust, hjust = hjust))`and returned `return(do.call(element_text, element_text_params))`. 



That way I can call your function like `rotatedAxisElementText(45, "y", element_text_params = list("size" = 10, "face" = "bold")`

Answer (score 14):

### OUTDATED - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60650595/1870254) for a simpler approach

---

To obtain readable x tick labels without additional dependencies, you want to use:

```r
  ... +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5)) +
  ...
```

This rotates the tick labels 90° counterclockwise and aligns them vertically at their end (`hjust = 1`) and their centers horizontally with the corresponding tick mark (`vjust = 0.5`).

Full example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot")
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

---

Note, that vertical/horizontal justification parameters `vjust`/`hjust` of `element_text` are relative to the text. Therefore, *`vjust`* is responsible for the *horizontal* alignment.

Without `vjust = 0.5` it would look like this:

```r
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Without `hjust = 1` it would look like this:

```r
q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

If for some (wired) reason you wanted to rotate the tick labels 90° clockwise (such that they can be read from the left) you would need to use: `q + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = -1))`.

All of this has already been discussed in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331400/1870254) but I come back to this question so often, that I want an answer from which I can just copy without reading the comments.

Answer (score 13):

The *ggpubr* package offers a shortcut that does the right thing by default (right align text, middle align text box to tick):

```r
library(ggplot2)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper", as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut, carat, data = diamonds, geom = "boxplot")
q + ggpubr::rotate_x_text()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Found with a GitHub search for the relevant argument names: https://github.com/search?l=R&q=element_text+angle+90+vjust+org%3Acran&type=Code

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `coord_flip()` is to use the `ggstance` package.
The advantage is that it makes it easier to combine the graphs with other graph types and you can, maybe more importantly, **set fixed scale ratios for your coordinate system**.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstance)

diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper", as.character(diamonds$cut))

ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(carat, cut)) + geom_boxploth()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>