# geom_bar stops working when group added

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this data:

```
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(id = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), prepost = c("pre", "post"), 
         value = 1:4)
```

this one works:

```
qplot(id, value, data = dd, fill = prepost, geom = "bar")
```

however, the next one gives the indicated error message.  The only difference between the two is the addition of `group = prepost` to the end of the command; however, since we had already written `fill = prepost` that should be the default group anyways.

```
> qplot(id, value, data = dd, fill = prepost, geom = "bar", group = prepost)
 Error in pmin(y, 0) : object 'y' not found
```

We can fix up the last one by adding `stat = "identity"` like this:

```
qplot(id, value, data = dd, fill = prepost, geom = "bar", group = prepost, 
      stat = "identity")
```

I have two questions:

(a) Why does the `qplot` which gave the error message not work when the others do work?

(b) If we use a continuous `y` aesthetic with `geom_bar` then what is supposed to happen if one does not specify `stat`?  From the first `qplot` it seems that in that case it acts as if `stat="identity"` but in the presence of `group` specifying `stat="identity"` or not reveals a difference.

(By the way, this question seems somewhat related although its different enough that it does not seem to answer this question: [Issue with ggplot2, geom_bar, and position="dodge": stacked has correct y values, dodged does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11604070/issue-with-ggplot2-geom-bar-and-position-dodge-stacked-has-correct-y-values))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question!

I will echo a earlier comment by [@joran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370258/1385941)

> I generally find that people are less confused with ggplot once they learn to stop using qplot

Your `qplot` call can be recreated using

```
ggplot(dd) + geom_bar(aes(x = id, y = value, fill = prepost))
```

Now, if you read the help for `geom_bar` it lists the aesthetics it understands, `group` is not one of them (so perhaps you can't expect it to work as you wish when you do this)

If you read the help for `group` you will see that it is an aesthetic that allows you to override the default interaction of all discrete variables.

If you group by `prepost` alone, you are not grouping by the discrete `x` axis variable `id`, which the default would be  included as well,

Therefore

```
ggplot(dd) + 
 geom_bar(aes(x=id, y = value, fill = prepost, group = interaction(id, prepost)))
```

works, but the grouping is entirely redundant as this is the default.

If you specify just `prepost` or `id` as your grouping, it confuses `stat_bin` (the underlying method that is crunching the numbers to create the values for the bar plot. Hence you need to use `stat_identity` instead.

---

EDIT: as noted by the OP in the comments below, this is related to a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/648) and will give better warnings in the next version (or th current dev version on github

From the NEWS

> - `stat_bin` now produces warning messages when it is used with set or
>     mapped y values. Previously, it was possible to use `stat_bin` and
>     also set/map y values; if there was one y value per group, it would
>     display the y values from the data, instead of the counts of cases for
>     each group. This usage is deprecated and will be removed in a future
>     version of ggplot2. (Winston Chang. Fixes #632)

Comment: (a) See ?aes_group_order
(b) When you provide melted data to ggplot, it does not know whether you have summarized the data or not. `stat=identity` merely tells ggplot that the data is already summarized. In the help for ?geom_bar this is covered: `Sometimes, bar charts are used not as a distributional summary, but instead of a dotplot. Generally, it's preferable to use a dotplot (see geom_point) as it has a better data-ink ratio. However, if you do want to create this type of plot, you can set y to the value you have calculated, and use stat='identity'`

Comment: @mnel, I don't think this really has anything to do with `qplot` vs. `ggplot1 since this fails too: `ggplot(dd, aes(id, value, fill = prepost, group = prepost)) + geom_bar()
` but on your other point you are right - I forgot about `id`. However, despite that it does work when we add `stat = "identity"` so that still leaves question (b).

Comment: @brandon, Of course it works with `stat="identity"`.  I already mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @user1189687, the default for `stat` in `geom_bar` is `bin`, thus `stat_bin`is called (as I state in the answer)

Comment: @mnel, Yes, `stat_bin` is the default but it does not actually seem to be using that if you specify `y` in these cases so I don't think that that is relevant.

Comment: I have just noticed that in this link https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/NEWS it mentions that specifying `y` with `stat_bin` is going to issue a warning in the next version of ggplot2 and that in the future it will be an error so I guess the intention is that users should not specify `y` with `stat_bin`.

Comment: @nmel, you did get the point about me missing `id` so if you add the link to the NEWS I just posted to your post I will accept it.