# How to rotate only text in annotation in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like this:

```
fake = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))

ggplot(data=fake, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point() + theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=-1, linetype=2, color="red") +
  annotate("text", x=-1, y=-1, label="Helpful annotation", color="red")
```

[image]

How would I rotate just the annotated text 90 degrees so that it is parallel to the reference line?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Just tell it the angle you want.

```
ggplot(data = fake, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    theme_bw() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = -1, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = -1, y = -1, label = "Helpful annotation", color = "red",
             angle = 90)
```

In `?geom_text` you can see that `angle` is a possible aesthetic, and `annotate` will pass it along, just like any other argument `geom_text` understands (such as the `x`, `y`, `label`, and `color` already being used).

Comment: the problem here is, that it doesn't really take the coordinates seriously. A y=0 for example will put half the text below the x-axis. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @PeterPan that has more to do with the text justification than the angle. The default is centered text, so it makes sense to rotate it around the center. For your case,  set `hjust = 0`. [See this answer for more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26684121/903061).

Comment: hmmm.. am I missing something? in `?geom_text` i do not see that `angle` is an option for parameter? I see mapping, data, stat, etc..

Comment: @orrymr [Here's the docs page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_text.html). Search the page for "angle" and you will find it. It's listed both under the "geom_text understands the following aesthetics..." list and is used in an example.