# Rotate label annotation in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to rotate an annotation on a ggplot in R, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27585588/how-to-rotate-only-text-in-annotation-in-ggplot), but using the label geometry with the background.

Using the code that works with `geom = "text"` or `geom_text` with `geom = 'label'` or `geom_label` results in un-rotated annotation.

```
fake = data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100))
ggplot(data = fake, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = -1, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
#    annotate(geom = "text", x = -1, y = -1, label = "Helpful annotation", color = "red",
#             angle = 90)
    annotate(geom = "label", x = -1, y = -1, label = "Helpful annotation", color = "red",
             angle = 90)
```

[image]

Text shows up with white background, but without rotation.

Is there an alternate way to rotate the label?

Comment: `geom_label()` which has the same parameters as `annotate(geom = "label"...` does not support rotation. You can use `ggtext::geom_richtext()` though. It uses the same arguments, in this case `angle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can't currently be done with `geom_label`. From the help: "Currently geom_label() does not support the check_overlap argument or the angle aesthetic."

But this can be done with a related function from the `ggtext` package:

```
ggplot(data = fake, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_vline(xintercept = -1, linetype = 2, color = "red") +
    ggtext::geom_richtext(x = -1, y = -1, label = "Helpful annotation", angle = 90)
```

[image]

Comment: ... or `annotate(geom = "richtext", ...)` if `ggtext` is loaded.