# Manipulating label position in ggtern

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In the `ggtern` package in R, I am trying to label the points, however I cannot find a way to position the labels in a way that looks better, I've played around with the position argument in `geom_text` but no luck.

```
require(ggtern)    
x  <- data.frame(
    A = c( 0.33, 0.4 ),
    B = c( 0.33, 0.5),
    C = c(0.33,0.1)
)
ggtern(data=x,aes(A,B,C)) + 
    geom_path(color="green")+
    geom_point(type="l",shape=21,size=1) +
    geom_text(label=c("(1/3,1/3,1/3)","(2/5,1/2,1/10)"), color="red")+
    theme_classic()
```

[image]

I'm wondering if anyone has dealt with this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the arguments `hjust` and `vjust`:

```
ggtern(data=x,aes(A,B,C)) + 
    geom_path(color="green")+
    geom_point(type="l",shape=21,size=1) +
    geom_text(label=c("(1/3,1/3,1/3)","(2/5,1/2,1/10)"), color="red", hjust=0, vjust=-1)+
    theme_classic()
```

Parameter `position` is *adjustment to use for overlapping points on this layer*, according to the help, so not what you need. For details on hjust and vjust, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot).

[image]