# ggplot labels on bargraph position

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, geom-bar, geom-text

I am REALLY sorry if this is a repeated question. But for some reason the answeres previously given did not work for me. 
I have the following df:

```
Country<-c("Chile", "Chile", "Finland","Finland")
Taxa<-c("Mammalia","Amphibia","Mammalia","Amphibia")
Loss<-c(0.15, 1, 0.2, 0.75)
df<-data.frame(Country, Taxa, Loss)
```

I want to display it as a ranking and add lables. This is what I got:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(Country, Loss), y=Loss)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Taxa), position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "", y = "")+
  ylim(0,1)+
  theme (legend.position="top", legend.title = element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(size = 17),
         axis.text.x  = element_text(size=17), 
         axis.text.y  = element_text(size=17), axis.title.y=element_text(size=17))+
  geom_text(aes(label = Loss), position=position_dodge(width=1))+
  coord_flip()
```

It works fine! Only that I cannot position the lables like I want. Id prefer for the labels to be next to the bar. I tried playing around with the `width` and also some `vjust` and `hjust`but the position never changed... What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using `vjust` and `hjust`, as you mentionned.

[How to use `vjust` and `hjust`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot)

I suppose that you want a label per bar, use `group = Taxa` in the `geom_text(aes())`.

[image]

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=reorder(Country, Loss), y=Loss)) +   
geom_bar(aes(fill = Taxa), position="dodge", stat="identity") + 
labs(x = "", y = "")+  ylim(0,1)+  theme (legend.position="top", 
legend.title = element_blank(),legend.text = element_text(size = 17),
axis.text.x  = element_text(size=17), axis.text.y  = element_text(size=17), 
axis.title.y=element_text(size=17))+ 
geom_text(aes(x = reorder(Country, Loss), label = Loss, group = Taxa), 
position=position_dodge(width=1), hjust = -1) 
+  coord_flip()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works great on this sample df. Now I have to make it work on the real deal...

Comment: Done. THANK YOU for the quick and helpful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Idea taken from `?geom_text`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Country, Loss), y=Loss, label = Loss, fill = Taxa)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Loss + 0.02), position = position_dodge(0.9), vjust = 0) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]