# Align axis label on the right with ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, graphics, ggplot2

Consider the following

```
d = data.frame(y=rnorm(120), 
               x=rep(c("bar", "long category name", "foo"), each=40))

ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
    geom_boxplot() + 
    theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, angle=90))
```

[image: plot with poorly aligned labels]

The x-axis labels are aligned by the center of the label. Is it possible to automatically align on the right so that every label would end right below the graph?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This is precisely what the `hjust` and `vjust` parameters are for in `ggplot`. They control the horizontal and vertical justification respectively and range from 0 to 1. See this question for more details on justifications and their values ([What do hjust and vjust do when making a plot using ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot)).

To get the labels the way you want you can use:

- `hjust = 0.95` (to leave some space between the labels and the axis)
- `vjust = 0.2` (to center them in this case)

---

```
ggplot(d,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_boxplot() + 
       theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=15, angle=90,hjust=0.95,vjust=0.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Why does the long name not align with the others? The final "e" in "long category name" is closer to the tick mark than "bar" or "foo".

Answer (score 19):

Alternatively, flip the axis, your customers will thank you and have less neck pain (plus, I find most boxplots easier to interpret with this orientation):

```
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image: Plot]