# Place labels inside symbols

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a x-y-plot that includes the labels inside the plot symbols.

My first attempt is this:

```
dx <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(3,5,8),z=c(1,10,20))
ggplot(data=dx, aes(x=x,y=y,label=as.factor(z)))+
geom_point(color="black",shape=1,size=6) + 
geom_text(hjust = 1, nudge_x = 0.04)
```

The result is almost ok, but the labels (`z`) are not centered in the plot symbol. This probably has to do with the parameters within `geom_text()`. What values do I have to choose so that the numbers (`z`) are centered in the circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can adjust using `hjust` and `vjust` ([here is a good post on how to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849)):

```
ggplot(data = dx, aes(x = x, y = y, label = as.factor(z))) +
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 1, size = 6) + 
  geom_text(hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5)
```

Or we can use [geom_label (ggplot2_2.1.0)](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_text.html), which will give us rectangles with rounded edges with labels inside.

```
ggplot(data = dx, aes(x = x, y = y, label = as.factor(z))) +
  geom_label()
```