# R ggplot2: how to write the y coordinate of every data point right next to it?

Tags: r

Example data set:

```
n   value
100000  20
200000  30
300000  25
400000  40
500000  12
```

The following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
data <- read.table("test", sep = "\t", header = TRUE,)
ggplot(data, aes(n, value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value))
dev.off()
```

will produce the following output:

[image]

However, I would like to get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Just use geom_text.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by @Roland, you can add text to your plot using `geom_text` or `geom_label` or `annotate`. Here is the code using `geom_text`:

```
data <- structure(list(n = c(100000L, 200000L, 300000L, 400000L, 500000L
), value = c(20L, 30L, 25L, 40L, 12L)), .Names = c("n", "value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=n, y=value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value))+
geom_text(aes(label=value), hjust=c(-1,0,0,-1,2), vjust=c(1,-.5,1.5,0,0))
```

[image]

`hjust` controls horizontal justification and `vjust` controls vertical justification. Details are given at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot).  Using `geom_label`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=n, y=value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value))+
geom_label(aes(label=value), hjust=c(-1,0,0,-1,2), vjust=c(1,-.5,1.5,0,0))
```

the result is:

[image]

It is also possible to use `annotate` as follows:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=n, y=value)) + 
geom_point(aes(n,value)) + geom_line(aes(n,value))+
annotate("text", x=data$n, y=data$value, label=data$value, 
   hjust=c(-1,0,0,-1,2), vjust=c(1,-.5,1.5,0,0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `library(ggrepel)` to minimize the point/label overlap automatically. I think it's more reliable than `position_jitter()` and useful if you can't/don't want to hardcode all of your dodge values:

```
ggplot(data, aes(n, value)) + 
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    # geom_text(aes(label = value), position = "jitter")
    geom_text_repel(aes(label = value),
                    point.padding = unit(.25, "lines"))
```

`geom_label_repel()` is available as well and there a lot of options for setting the "dodge" areas size.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the `data` argument in the call of `ggplot` the following calls of geom_point etc. will inherit it, so you don't need to specify it again. Using dplyr piping notation (%>%) and `geom_text` the result would be:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tribble(
   ~n, ~value,
   100000,  20,
   200000,  30,
   300000,  25,
   400000,  40,
   500000,  12
) %>% ggplot(aes(n, value)) + 
                geom_point() + 
                geom_line() + 
                geom_text(aes(label=value), nudge_y=1, nudge_x=-10000)
```

This is essentially the same as calling

```
ggplot(data, aes(n, value)) + 
       geom_point() + 
       geom_line() + 
       geom_text(aes(label=value), nudge_y=1, nudge_x=-10000)
```

[image]