# How to utilize \n or similar in paste0() for axis-labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, paste

**Question:** how to utilize `n\` or similar to create two text-lines in `x-axis label` written with `paste0`

I have

[image]

As you can see, I currently have two independent lines on the `x-axis` as currently written with `labels = paste0("LN: \nLND: ", paste0(seq(0,80,5))))`.

I would like the numerical value yielded from `seq(0,80,5)` to appear in  both lines, but with `%` written behind one the of texts.

Expected output:

[image]

> **Bonus question:** is it possible to manually right/left/center align the two text lines I am trying to create on `x-axis label`?

Written with

```
ggplot(p, aes(x=value, y=os.neck, color=name_new, fill=name_new)) + 

  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, stroke=1, fill="white") + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles=.5, size=1.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,5),
                     name="Lymph nodal yield",
                     labels = paste0("LN: \nLND: ", paste0(seq(0,80,5)))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,180,20),
                     name="Months to death")
```

Data sample `p`

```
p <- structure(list(value = c(22.2, 18, 9.1, 11, 14, 15, 9, 6, 3, 
25, 16, 4, 6, 10, 13, 12.1, 33, 16, 6, 9, 4.3, 23, 9, 8, 13, 
5, 30, 25, 33.3, 3, 9, 33.3, 9, 12, 7, 38, 60, 5, 71.4, 7, 15, 
25, 4, 16.7, 6, 15, 11.1, 9, 8, 42.9, 7, 4, 16.7, 6, 10, 10, 
62.5, 8, 25, 4, 11.1, 9, 10, 14, 14, 3, 4, 50, 6, 6, 20, 33.3, 
3, 7.7, 26, 13, 7.7, 13, 13, 13, 3, 7, 16.7, 6, 5, 20, 10, 15, 
29, 7, 6, 11, 11.8, 17, 71.4, 14, 33.3, 18, 22, 9), os.neck = c(11.5, 
11.5, 74.38, 74.38, 17.02, 7.89, 96.03, 40.48, 17.74, 14.65, 
14.65, 62.46, 12.55, 9.92, 26.05, 45.47, 45.47, 17.38, 39.72, 
51.45, 8.61, 8.61, 76.98, 67.09, 94.79, 72.15, 93.93, 17.05, 
12.48, 12.48, 91.6, 15.87, 15.87, 11.04, 67.22, 67.02, 8.94, 
8.94, 6.6, 6.6, 5.09, 10.68, 10.68, 17.15, 17.15, 0.07, 5.19, 
5.19, 40.77, 0.2, 0.2, 170.88, 5.55, 5.55, 1.61, 1.61, 38.28, 
38.28, 10.58, 10.58, 32.99, 32.99, 110.98, 103.69, 122.32, 14.78, 
42.74, 4.04, 4.04, 8.28, 84.96, 11.7, 11.7, 49.97, 49.97, 120.48, 
52.6, 52.6, 71.26, 16.3, 100.14, 55.03, 6.51, 6.51, 89.89, 51.71, 
51.71, 24.97, 55.66, 21.91, 81.48, 30.92, 1.58, 1.58, 7.52, 7.52, 
30.75, 30.75, 3.45, 19.22), name_new = structure(c(3L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("n_fjernet0", "n_fjernet1", "lnd1"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

Comment: Please check your data sample. It does not work.

Comment: Hi @Jan. My apologies. It has been corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fiddled a bit with your `paste0` statement, for me the easiest solution is to repeat `paste0(seq(0,80,5))` to get the desired results:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(p, aes(x=value, y=os.neck, color=name_new, fill=name_new)) + 

  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, stroke=1, fill="white") + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles=.5, size=1.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,5),
                     name="Lymph nodal yield",
                     labels =  paste0(paste0("LN: ", seq(0,80,5), "\n"), paste0("LND: ", seq(0,80,5), "%"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,180,20),
                     name="Months to death")
```

[image]

You can change the alignment with `hjust`, see the great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263849/what-do-hjust-and-vjust-do-when-making-a-plot-using-ggplot).

Add the following code to your `ggplot()`

**Left-aligned:**

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 0))
```

[image]

**Right-aligned:**

```
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Of yourse could do it with `paste0()` like this:

```r
myseq <- paste0(seq(0,80,5))
paste0("LN: ", myseq, "\nLND: ", paste0(myseq, "%"))
#>  [1] "LN: 0\nLND: 0%"   "LN: 5\nLND: 5%"   "LN: 10\nLND: 10%" "LN: 15\nLND: 15%"
#>  [5] "LN: 20\nLND: 20%" "LN: 25\nLND: 25%" "LN: 30\nLND: 30%" "LN: 35\nLND: 35%"
#>  [9] "LN: 40\nLND: 40%" "LN: 45\nLND: 45%" "LN: 50\nLND: 50%" "LN: 55\nLND: 55%"
#> [13] "LN: 60\nLND: 60%" "LN: 65\nLND: 65%" "LN: 70\nLND: 70%" "LN: 75\nLND: 75%"
#> [17] "LN: 80\nLND: 80%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But a more elegant solution would be with `sprintf()`. The result is identical with less code. You can give one input to `sprintf()` and use it multiple times:

```r
sprintf("LN: %1$s\nLND: %1$s%%", seq(0,80,5))
#>  [1] "LN: 0\nLND: 0%"   "LN: 5\nLND: 5%"   "LN: 10\nLND: 10%" "LN: 15\nLND: 15%"
#>  [5] "LN: 20\nLND: 20%" "LN: 25\nLND: 25%" "LN: 30\nLND: 30%" "LN: 35\nLND: 35%"
#>  [9] "LN: 40\nLND: 40%" "LN: 45\nLND: 45%" "LN: 50\nLND: 50%" "LN: 55\nLND: 55%"
#> [13] "LN: 60\nLND: 60%" "LN: 65\nLND: 65%" "LN: 70\nLND: 70%" "LN: 75\nLND: 75%"
#> [17] "LN: 80\nLND: 80%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is a hack but i seems to do what you want (?). Unfortunately, it doesn't look good with all that text crammed inn there i my opinion.

```
ggplot(p, aes(x=value, y=os.neck, color=name_new, fill=name_new)) + 

  geom_point(size=2, shape=21, stroke=1, fill="white") + 
  geom_quantile(quantiles=.5, size=1.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,80,5),
                     name="Lymph nodal yield",
                     labels = paste0("LN:   ",paste0(seq(0,80,5)), paste0('\nLND: '), paste0(seq(0,80,5),'%'))) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,180,20),
                     name="Months to death") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 6,hjust = 0))
```

[image: picture]