# ggplot - while using facet grid, how to center both the labels which appear on the top and the labels which appear on the right side?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is a minimal example with the `mtcars` dataset that reflects something else I am doing:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = qsec, color = as.factor(cyl), fill = as.factor(cyl)))+
  geom_density(alpha = .3)+
  facet_grid(rows = vars(vs), cols = vars(am))+
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = "black"))
```

This will give us the following plot:

[image]

I want to make both the labels which appear on top of the graph, as well as the labels that appear on the right side of the graph to be in the center of their respective boxes. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I tried using `strip.text = element_text()` and then playing around with various `hjust` and `vjust` values, but I just can't seem to find the right ones. Whenever I find the correct value for centering, say, top labels, this value of `hjust` will also cause the labels on the right to go out of their boxes, and vice versa.

Any help with the correct values of `hjust` or `vjust`, or any other approaches to solve this problem would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7267364/7023826 I would do hjust = .5, vjust =.5 to keep it centered

Comment: When I run your code, the labels are centered.

Comment: When I run the above code exactly as written, the facet text is perfectly centered. You seem to have some sort of theme applied which is causing the off-centering, since you have no grid, visible axis lines and white facet strip boxes, none of which are default in ggplot. Did you perhaps use `set_theme` somewhere? Try restarting R, loading only ggplot and running exactly the same code again.

Comment: I see! That's correct, I am using a theme that I have set beforehand. Thank you for spotting this.