# How to rotate the axis labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following graph that I generated using ggplot2 [image]

I had `finalPlot` as the ggplot object. To add labels I used

```
finalPlot + stat_bin() + scale_x_continuous('Solution Cost') + scale_y_continuous('Number of Solutions')`
```

How can I change the orientation of the y axis label to make it appear horizontal and if possible span it across two lines like

```
Number of
Solutions
```

Comment: As far as I can see the answer below is now obsolete since `'opts'` is deprecated (is now `'theme'`) as is `theme_text()` (for `'element_text'`)..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the rotation angle of the axis text you need to use `element_text()`. See [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) for some examples. For spacing over two lines I would add a `"\n"` on the location in the string where you want to put the newline.

This will set the correct orientation for the y axis text and force a line break:

```
finalPlot + ylab("Number of\nSolutions") + 
    theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0))
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want. This one changes the orientation of the ticks. I want to rotate the axis label, not the axis tick label

Comment: You can probably take this solution and adapt it to your situation quite easily...

Comment: But I do not know what the corresponding parameters will be :(

Comment: Just type `theme_text()` on the command prompt to get a list of the options you can set. I guess what need is `title.text`

Comment: `axis.title.theme.y` is for the axis label
`axis.text.theme.y` is for the axis values

Answer (score 22):

The syntax has changed in recent versions of ggplot2; if you try the above answer, you'll get

> Error: Use 'theme' instead. (Defunct; last used in version 0.9.1)

These days you should use

```
finalPlot + ylab("Number of\nSolutions") + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0))
```