# How to plot time series type of plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this matrix called `mymat` with more than 70000 rows. I want to plot the `key.related.sheet` (samples) where the values from `Num_Good_SNPs_A` columns will be the X-axis and the `IBS_from` columns will be the Y-axis. How can I get this done in R?

```
    mymat<-structure(c("AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0010", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0022", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0063", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0079", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0087", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0105", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0108", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0112", 
"AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0118", "AOGC-02-0010:AOGC-02-0161", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0032", 
"AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0054", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0067", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0083", 
"AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0090", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0097", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0125", 
"AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0139", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0140", "AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0154", 
"AOGC-02-0022:AOGC-08-0167", "1.12", "-0.0176", "0.0253", "0.0132", 
"-0.00835", "-0.0205", "-0.00759", "-0.0134", "-0.0351", "0.00399", 
"0.00021", "-0.0144", "0.013", "0.0035", "-0.00973", "-0.0109", 
"-0.0000367", "0.0196", "0.00304", "-0.00509", "-0.0224", "16987", 
"13360", "12837", "11836", "12097", "13016", "15128", "14564", 
"13262", "14685", "14944", "13516", "14257", "11146", "13545", 
"15112", "13164", "13343", "10284", "12705", "10599", "1.12", 
"-0.00582", "0.0171", "0.0107", "-0.0132", "-0.0214", "-0.0145", 
"0.00123", "-0.0268", "0.00374", "0.00549", "-0.0215", "0.0285", 
"0.0038", "-0.0133", "-0.0268", "-0.00474", "0.0259", "0.00451", 
"-0.0111", "-0.0234", "14152", "11228", "10739", "9903", "10134", 
"10871", "12597", "12141", "11083", "12246", "12573", "11368", 
"11988", "9410", "11420", "12699", "11084", "11197", "8642", 
"10710", "8957", "1.13", "-0.00634", "0.0192", "0.0232", "-0.0328", 
"-0.0383", "-0.0318", "-0.0104", "-0.000175", "-0.0178", "0.0283", 
"-0.0158", "0.0265", "0.00121", "-0.00154", "-0.0118", "0.00984", 
"-0.0346", "0.00538", "0.0209", "-0.0485", "7158", "5720", "5478", 
"5049", "5178", "5480", "6374", "6133", "5613", "6187", "6358", 
"5852", "6095", "4772", "5835", "6433", "5706", "5658", "4377", 
"5560", "4678", "1.15", "0.0139", "0.0155", "0.0113", "-0.0232", 
"-0.0175", "-0.00998", "-0.00379", "0.00973", "-0.0469", "0.0484", 
"0.000755", "0.0332", "0.00556", "0.0302", "-0.049", "-0.00191", 
"-0.0276", "0.00223", "0.037", "-0.0643", "3759", "2986", "2849", 
"2634", "2681", "2875", "3394", "3237", "2932", "3243", "3313", 
"3023", "3163", "2499", "3047", "3311", "2897", "2966", "2303", 
"2869", "2342"), .Dim = c(21L, 9L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "100", "101", "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110"), c("key.related.sheet", 
"IBS_from:324711SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:324711SNPS", "IBS_from:266640SNPS", 
"Num_Good_SNPs_A:266640SNPS", "IBS_from:133224SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:133224SNPS", 
"IBS_from:66441SNPS", "Num_Good_SNPs_A:66441SNPS")))
```

Here is the code I have tried:

```
mydf <- as.data.frame(mymat)
rownames(mydf) <- mydf[,"key.related.sheet"] 
mydf[, grepl("IBS",colnames(mydf))] <- lapply(mydf[, grepl("IBS",colnames(mydf))], function (x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
mydf[, grepl("Num_Good",colnames(mydf))] <- lapply(mydf[, grepl("Num_Good",colnames(mydf))], function (x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
effCis <- grep('^IBS',names(mydf));
find.measurements <- grep("^Num_Good_SNPs", names(mydf))

#xlim <- c(1,length(find.measurements));
#xlim <- range(mydf[,find.measurements],na.rm=T);
xlim <- c(1,length(effCis))
ylim <- range(mydf[,effCis],na.rm=T);
ylim[1L] <- floor(ylim[1L]/0.1)*0.1;
ylim[2L] <- ceiling(ylim[2L]/0.1)*0.1;
yticks <- seq(ylim[1L],ylim[2L],0.1);

xticks <- seq(from = max(mydf[, find.measurements]), to = min(mydf[, find.measurements]), length.out = length(effCis))
#xticks <- seq(from = max(mydf[, find.measurements]), to = min(mydf[, find.measurements]), length.out = 7)

plot(NA,xlim=c(min(xticks), max(xticks)), ylim=ylim,xlab='Number of good SNPs used',ylab='Samples',xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=FALSE)
#plot(mydf[,effCis],mydf[,find.measurements])

par(mar=c(5,4,4,5)+.1)
mtext("IBS", side=4, line= 2.5)
#plot(NA,xlim=c(min(xticks), max(xticks)), ylim=ylim,xlab='Numbers of good SNPs used',ylab='IBS',xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=TRUE)
abline(v=xticks,col='lightgrey');
abline(h=yticks,col='lightgrey');
abline(h=0,lwd=2);


axis(side = 1, at = xticks)

##axis(2L,yticks,sprintf('%.1f',yticks),las=1L,font=2L,cex.axis=0.7);
#axis(4L,yticks,sprintf('%.1f',yticks),las=1L,font=2L,cex.axis=0.7);
axis(4L,yticks,sprintf('%.1f',yticks),las=1L,font=2L,cex.axis=0.6);

hybrid.col <- data.frame(hybrid=seq_len(nrow(mydf)),col=rainbow(nrow(mydf)),stringsAsFactors=F);

#cryptic.col <- data.frame(cryptic=seq_len(nrow(mydf)),col=rainbow(nrow(mydf)),stringsAsFactors=F);
#with((mydf[which(mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]]>=0.59 & mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]] <= 0.9),]), text(xlab ~ ylab, labels = rownames(mydf)[mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]]>=0.59 & mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]] <= 0.9]), pos = 4)

#rownames(mydf)[mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]]>=0.59 & mydf[,colnames(mydf)[grepl("IBS_",colnames(mydf))][1]] <= 0.9]


#hybrid.col <- data.frame(hybrid=seq_len(nrow(mydf)),stringsAsFactors=F);
splineN <- 200L;
for (ri in seq_len(nrow(hybrid.col))) {
  hybrid <- hybrid.col$hybrid[ri];
  col <- hybrid.col$col[ri];
  x <- xticks;
  y <- c(as.matrix(mydf[hybrid,effCis]));
  points(x,y,pch=16L,xpd=NA);
  with(spline(x,y,splineN),{
    lines(x,y,col=col,lwd=2,xpd=NA);
    localwin <- which(x > 2 & x < 3);
    tp <- which.min (abs (diff ( y [localwin]) ) );
    if (length (tp) > 0L) points (x[localwin [tp]] , y[localwin[tp]] , col = col,pch=4L);
    localwin <- which (x > 2 & x < 5);
    tp <- which.min (diff (y[localwin]));
    if (length(tp) > 0L) {
      m <- diff(y[localwin[seq(tp,len=2L)]])/diff(x[localwin[seq(tp,len=2L)]]);
      if (is.finite(m)) abline(y[localwin[tp]]-m*x[localwin[tp]],m,col=col,lty=2L);
    };
  });
};

abline(h = 0.5, lwd = 2, lty = 15 , col = "Black");
abline(h = 1.0, lwd = 2, lty = 15, col = "Black");
abline(h = 0, lwd = 2, lty = 15, col = "Black");
```

Comment: @zx8754 Please see the code I have tried. However it does not correctly account for the number of SNPs (i.e. X-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table` to reshape it to 'long' format as there are multiple `patterns` in the dataset.  As `matrix` can hold only a single class (and when there is a single `character` element in the `matrix`, the whole dataset will be `character` matrix), when we convert it to `data.table`, the columns will be all `character` class.  The numeric columns are converted back to their original class and then use `ggplot` to plot the columns based on the OP's description.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
melt(as.data.table(mymat), measure =  patterns("^IBS", "^Num_Good"), 
     value.name = c("IBS", "Num_Good")) %>%
.[, c("IBS", "Num_Good") := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = IBS:Num_Good] %>% 
.[, Grp := cut(IBS, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.3, 0.5, 1.2, Inf))] %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, col = key.related.sheet)) + 
       geom_line() + 
       facet_wrap(~Grp)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way we can have different colours for lines that fall at the range of IBS value of `0-0.3`, `0.3-0.5` and `0.9-1.2`? I would like a line plot instead.

Comment: @MAPK In that case, use `geom_line`

Comment: @MAPK We can create a group with `cut` and use it

Comment: How do I get rid of the `key.related.sheet` labels on the right? It occupies most of the space in the plot.

Comment: Another issue with the plot is it breaks the plot into two sections, one where we have lines with IBS close to zero and the other with IBS close to 1.2. Can we have everything in the same plot?

Comment: @MAPK Try with `scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)`

Comment: @MAPK It is because we used `facet_wrap`.  Removing them and adding the Grp as a grouping variable should fix it, but then it will be difficult to identify.

Comment: @MAPK Does `%>%
      ggplot(., aes(x = Num_Good, y = IBS, col = key.related.sheet, group = Grp)) + 
         
           geom_line() +scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)` work for you

Comment: No it didn't. I just used `scale_colour_discrete(guide = FALSE)`, omitting `facet_wrap(~Grp)` and it just worked fine. How do I rotate the face of the plot? That is I want to keep the IBS (Y-)axis on the right instead of left?

Comment: @MAPK Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063701/how-to-rotate-the-axis-labels-in-ggplot2