# How to rotate a graph in a specific angle?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, rotation, angle

I would like to rotate a ggplot2 graph by a self-specified angle. I found how to [rotate the axis text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063701/how-to-rotate-the-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) with `element_text(angle = 20)`. I would like to do something similar with the whole plot.

Reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123)

data_plot <- data.frame(x = sort(rnorm(1000)),
                        y = sort(rnorm(1000)))

ggplot(data_plot, aes(y, x)) +
    geom_line() # + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(angle = 20))
```

This graph should be rotated:

[image]

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312791/903061) does it, except for the clipping, I'm sure there's a way to nest a viewport inside a bigger one to get your result.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, perfect solution!

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712801/how-to-combine-two-ggplots-with-one-rotated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a rough idea, calling your plot `p`:

```
library(grid)
pushViewport(viewport(name = "rotate", angle = 20, clip = "off", width = 0.7, height = 0.7))
print(p, vp = "rotate")
```

[image]

You'll probably want to tailor the `width` and `height` to the angle and aspect ratio you want.