# R function for making rotated scatter plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, scatter-plot, r-plotly

I am working on a Shiny app that produces some data visualizations. I was wondering if there was a way to rotate a scatter plot's axis 45 degrees. (i.e. the scatter plot would have a diamond shape when visualized). An example of the plot that I am looking for is here https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-018-06912-1

Would I just have to do this through java script, or is there r functionality that can help me?

Comment: answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48323534/ggplot2-how-to-rotate-a-graph-in-a-specific-angle

Comment: Yes, that is it, but would this work in a Shiny Context?