# rotating axis labels in date format

Tags: r, ggplot2

does anyone know how to rotate axis ticks in the date format with ggplot2?
I want to get labels with "Date-Month" (ex. "1985-5") with a 45° angle on the x axis.

data sample:

```
Station Date Ptot
A 1980-02 16
A 1980-03 19
A 1980-04 40
A 1980-05 48
A 1980-06 NA
A 1980-07 18.5
A 1980-08 24.6
B 1980-07 50.8
B 1980-08 28.9
B 1980-09 32.9
B 1980-10 47.9
B 1980-11 16.3
```

I tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

plot <- ggplot(data=na.omit(data), aes(x=Date, y=Ptot, group=Station))+
   geom_line()+
   facet_grid(Station~.)+
   scale_x_date(breaks = "year", labels=date_format("%Y-%m"))+
   xlab("Year")+
   ylab("Prec (mm)")+
   labs(colour = "Station")+
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
   theme_bw()

plot
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: you'll have to provide a better reproducible example than that with data, and your complete code.

Comment: OK, I just improved details in the question...

Comment: Check @Didzis' edit where he explains the problem with your `Date` column.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

First, you should make column `Date` as date. As it do not have the day provided, you should add for example 01 to each date and convert them.

```
data$Date<-as.Date(paste(data$Date,"-01",sep=""),format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

To get correct placement of labels under x axis you should set not just `angle=` but also `hjust=1` to ensure that end of the label is placed under the tick mark. Also `theme_bw()` should be placed before theme specification of axis texts.

```
ggplot(data=na.omit(data), aes(x=Date, y=Ptot, group=Station))+
  geom_line()+
  facet_grid(Station~.)+
  scale_x_date(breaks = "month", labels=date_format("%Y-%m"))+
  xlab("Year")+
  ylab("Prec (mm)")+theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I was just about to write that.

Comment: Thanks! I din't mention that I had done the date transformation of my "Date" column... I still have to learn to optimize the use of this forum. My problem was the position of theme_bw()

Comment: @user2165907 theme_bw() also set parameters for the axis.text, so it should be placed before your parameters.

Comment: UPDATE you now might need to add `vjust = 0.5` to get better alignment. Thanks to  @jupp0r's [comments in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1331400/4606130)  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))