# Too many x-axis values on ggplot2 scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would be very thankful for anyone with advice on this. I think this is a *similar* to question to one previously posted here ([Too many factors on x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951216/too-many-factors-on-x-axis)).

I  have a dataset as follows:

```
> head(outputDF)
    var1    var2             snpR stepD
1 A    B 1.55809163171629     6
2 A    C 1.57475543745267     6
3 A    D 1.36003481988361     4
4 A    E 1.60338829251054     4
5 A    F 1.54720598772132     5
6 B    C 1.10321616677002     2
```

I have a nice scatterplot from the function:

```
ggplot(outputDF, aes(x=snpR, y=stepD)) +geom_point(shape=1) +xlab("SNPR Distance") +
  ylab("StepD Distance")
```

But the problem is that since there are so many distinct snpR values on the x-axis, the x-axis numbers are unreadable, and there are too many vertical grids coming off each of these x-axis number labels.

I know it is a trick with scale_x_continuous but I am just lost playing around with it...

Comment: It sounds like snpR is a `factor`, but should be a `numeric` variable. This means that ggplot is giving it a discrete scale rather than a continuous one.

Comment: that did it! Thank you so much! I just did character(numeric(snpR))