# Shiny/R: Too many factors on line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm using ggplot2 and shiny to create a graph, however there are too many factors appearing on the x axis.

[image]

```
  output$housePlot <- renderPlot({
  ggplot(data=houseratio, aes(x=Year, y=Ratio, group=Region, colour=Region)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
  })
```

I've tried reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951216/too-many-factors-on-x-axis) but I can't get the seq() right. My data is in long format, looks like this:

```
Year    Ratio   Region
1983 Q1 2.9 Northern
1983 Q2 3   Northern
1983 Q3 3.1 Northern
1983 Q4 3   Northern
...
2015 Q2 5.1 UK
2015 Q3 5.1 UK
2015 Q4 5.2 UK
2016 Q1 5.2 UK
```

Using this code:

```
output$housePlot <- renderPlot({
ggplot(data=houseratio, aes(x=Year, y=Ratio, group=Region, colour=Region)) +
scale_x_discrete(breaks = seq(1, 1864, by = 4)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point()
})
```

All the factors disappear!

[image]

I only need each year showing, not individual quarters. Any suggestions?

(Thanks)

Comment: Try `scale_x_date` or `scale_x_datetime` http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest route is ultimately to make 'Year' a numeric type. This requires a few conversions:

```
library("zoo")
library("dplyr")

houseratio <- houseratio %>% mutate(Year = Year %>% as.character() %>% 
                                    as.yearqtr() %>% as.numeric())
```