# Creating Hexbins with Dates in R hexbin()

Tags: r, date, time-series, binning

I am trying to create hexbins where the x-axis is a date using the hexbin function in the hexbin package in R.  When I feed in my data, it seems to convert the dates into a numeric, which gets displayed on the x-axis.  I want it force the x-axis to be a date.

```
#Create Hex Bins
hbin <- hexbin(xData$Date, xData$YAxis, xbins = 80)

#Plot using rBokeh
figure() %>% 
  ly_hexbin(hbin)
```

This gives me:

[image: Hexbin Graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a brute force approach using the underlying grid plotting package. The axes are ugly;  maybe someone with better `grid` skills than I could pretty them up.

```
# make some data
x = seq.Date(as.Date("2015-01-01"),as.Date("2015-12-31"),by='days')
y = sample(x)

# make the plot and capture the plot
p <- plot(hexbin(x,y),yaxt='n',xaxt='n')

# calculate the ticks
x_ticks_date <- 
x_ticks <- axTicks(1, log = FALSE, usr = as.numeric(range(x)),
                axp=c(as.numeric(range(x)) ,5))
class(x_ticks_date) <- 'Date'
y_ticks_date <- 
y_ticks <- axTicks(1, log = FALSE, usr = as.numeric(range(y)),
                   axp=c(as.numeric(range(y)) ,5))
class(y_ticks_date) <- 'Date'

# push the ticks to the view port.
pushViewport(p$plot.vp@hexVp.off)
grid.xaxis(at=x_ticks, label = format(y_ticks_date))
grid.yaxis(at=y_ticks, label = format(y_ticks_date))
```

Comment: In retrospect, a better solution would be to use ggplot2, combined with [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989) to make pretty axis with far less work.  If someone added that answer, I'd upvote it.