# Resizing X labels of ggplot2 v0.8.9

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can i change the size of X labels under `ggplot2 v0.8.9`, i tried to use the `theme()` function but this last one is exclusive to upper version.

Thanks,

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version?

Comment: I think you want to use `opts` instead, iirc.

Comment: i have to, because i am using an old version of R, the only one compatible with my tools

Comment: Why not simply upgrade R to the current version_

Comment: because the tool that i use is no more supported (omnetpp-r)

Comment: Last `opts` docs I can find is [not very useful](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/opts.html).

Comment: You make me in the right way, i just found a solution with opt after reading another thread and understing how to use opt ;) , i am going to publish the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to use the old opt() function like this:

```
// Considering that the plot is P
P+opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=10))
```

By the same way it is also possible to rotate the label or change the font by replacing size with angle, font, etc...