# ggplot x-axis labels with all x-axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I'm plotting `ggplot` with `geom_point`. The x-axis will be individuals' ID, and y-axis is variable A. How can I ggplot all and individual ID values on the x-axis without overlapping labels? ID may not be continuous.

df sample (actual rows are much longer)

```
> df
ID     A
1      4
2      12
3      45
5      1
```

Code for the plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = A)) + geom_point()
```

Above code has x-axis in intervals, but not presenting individual ID.

Thanks!

Comment: assuming that your ID names are very long. Rotating the labels might be a good idea? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ID <- 1:50
A <- runif(50,1,100)

df <- data.frame(ID,A)

ggplot(df, aes(x = ID, y = A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous("ID", labels = as.character(ID), breaks = ID)
```

This will produce this image:

[image]

So you'll get a label for every ID-value. If you'd like to remove the gridlines (There are too much for my taste) you can remove them by adding `theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())`

**EDIT:** The easier way would be to just use ID as a factor for the plot. like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(ID), y = A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("ID")
```

[image]

The advantage of this method is that you don't get empty spaces from missing IDs

**EDIT2:** Concerning your Problem with overlapping labels: I'm guessing it comes from a large number of IDs to be plotted. There are several ways we can deal with this. So lets say your plot looks like this:

[image]

One idea would be to hide every 3rd label from the x-axis by modifying the break argument of the axis:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(ID), y = A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = ID[c(T,F,F)]) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("ID")
```

which leads to this:

[image]

If hiding labels is not an option, you could split your plot into subplots.

```
df$group <- as.numeric(cut(df$ID, 4))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(ID), y = A)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("ID") +
  facet_wrap(~group, ncol = 1, scales = "free_x")
```

which leads to this:

[image]

Comment: thanks! that's what I need. And how can I increase the space between the x labels like you did in the second plot? Mine's are overlapping.

Comment: why are your labels overlapping? I'm guessing you're trying to plot a lot of IDs. I've edited my answer and added some information, let me know if my ideas work for you

Comment: Fantastic! I had been looking for something like this everywhere!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when ID is discrete and discontinuous:

```
df$ID <- as.character(df$ID)
xlab <- sort(unique(df$ID))
ggplot(df, aes(x= ID, y= A)) + geom_point() + scale_x_discrete(labels= xlab)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add `+ xlim()` and `+ ylim()` to show the full x axis and y axis (i.e. to make the x axis and y axis start at zero).

#### Reproducible example

If this is your ggplot:

```r
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

**simply add these two lines to make the x and y axes start at zero**:

```r
iris %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +     
  xlim(0, 8.2) +     # add this line for x axis limits
  ylim(0, 4.5)       # add this line for y axis limits
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is not what the question was about