# vis_miss make column titles vertical

Tags: r, naniar

how do you rotate the column titles in vis_miss (naniar library)?
They are tilted in the default settings, I would like the titles to be vertical (parallel to the y-axis of the graph).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to help to be helped.

Answer (score 1):

The current behaviour of `vis_miss()` is the following:

```r
library(visdat)
vis_miss(airquality)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As visdat is built on top of ggplot2, you rotate the y axis labels 90 degrees, like so:

```r
library(visdat)
library(ggplot2)

vis_miss(airquality) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Which I found from this: [Rotating and spacing axis labels in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Your plots are equal. There is no change since the axis which has to be rotated is the x axis.

Comment: axis.text.x should replace axis.text.y since he's talking about the rownames displayed at a 45 degree angle.

Answer (score 0):

`theme(axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 90))` or whatever other angle degree instead of `axis.text.y` to change the variable labels on top.