# how to correct x axis text placement when the angle is between 45 and 90?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm struggling to understand the interactions for ggplot's axis.text.x: `angle`, `hjust` and `vjust`.  Everything I've read works when angle is between 0 and 45, but not for angles > 45 and < 90.

Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)   
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(1000 * mpg, hp)) +
      geom_point()
```

The first plot with `angle = 90` looks as expected,

```
p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

However, when decreasing the angle by only 1 degree compared with the plot above (from `angle = 90` to `angle = 89`), the axis labels are shifted down.

```
p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 89, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Could you add pics of current and expected output?

Comment: Try looking at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2

Comment: Things look somewhat OK if just using `vjust = 0.5`, but I can't figure out the logic of what `hjust` is doing in your second case.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour lies all the way inside an unexported function, `ggplot2:::rotate_just()`, which can be found if you run debug on `ggplot2:::element_grob.element_text` -> `titleGrob` -> `title_spec`.

This is what its code looks like, in my current package version (ggplot2 3.4.2):

```
> ggplot2:::rotate_just
function (angle, hjust, vjust) 
{
    angle <- (angle %||% 0)%%360
    if (0 <= angle & angle < 90) {
        hnew <- hjust
        vnew <- vjust
    }
    else if (90 <= angle & angle < 180) {
        hnew <- 1 - vjust
        vnew <- hjust
    }
    else if (180 <= angle & angle < 270) {
        hnew <- 1 - hjust
        vnew <- 1 - vjust
    }
    else if (270 <= angle & angle < 360) {
        hnew <- vjust
        vnew <- 1 - hjust
    }
    list(hjust = hnew, vjust = vnew)
}
```

In your 1st case, with `angle = 90, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5`, the second set of conditions are fulfilled, so the modified values are `hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1`.

In your 2nd case, with `angle = 89, hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5`, the first set of conditions are fulfilled, so the values remain unchanged as `hjust = 1, vjust = 0.5`.

If you want the 2nd case's vertical alignment to mimic that of the first, setting `vjust = 1` will do the job. (Though I suppose this is an edge case for theoretical interest, because I can't think of many reasons for one to use angle = 89 instead of 90 in real life...)

Comment: the edge case `angle = 89` was included to show the show the unexpected sharp change in behavior from 90 to 89
the desired angle was 75 - a bit easier to read than 90 and hogs less vertical space
your answer helps regardless

Comment: @KJB one additional suggestion: you can add `debug = TRUE` inside `element_text()` to visualize where the text grobs are being "anchored"; I find it helps when making detailed justification adjustments. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying both `vjust = 0.5` and `hjust = 0.5` then you avoid the problem.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = 1000*mpg, y = hp)) +
geom_point() +
theme(
axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, vjust = .5, hjust = .5)
)
```

[image: Result]