# Altering the x-axis values in a ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is the first time I have posted. Please excuse me if this question has been answered elsewhere, or if it is poorly explained.

```
> summary(pivoteddata)
          country       year               value      
 Belgium      :35   Length:175         Min.   :54.50  
 France       :35   Class :character   1st Qu.:80.30  
 Italy        :35   Mode  :character   Median :86.10  
 Spain        :35                      Mean   :82.37  
 United States:35                      3rd Qu.:87.55  
 Afghanistan  : 0                      Max.   :95.50  
 (Other)      : 0                      NA's   :164 



   > dput(head(pivoteddata, 20))
structure(list(country = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L), .Label = c("Afghanistan" - deleted countries - "Zimbabwe"), 
class = "factor"), year = c("X1984", "X1985", "X1986", 
"X1987", "X1988", "X1989", "X1990", "X1991", "X1992", "X1993", 
"X1994", "X1995", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", 
"X2001", "X2002", "X2003"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 90.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This is the code for my scatter graph: -

```
practiceplot <- ggplot(pivoteddata, aes(x=year, y=value, group=country, 
                        color=country, size=10)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point()
```

...and what it looks like: -

[X axis using original values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAPeC.png)

I want to change the x-axis values, so added to the code :-

```
ggplot(pivoteddata, aes(x=year, y=value, group=country, 
                        color=country, size=10)) +
  **scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35), 
                     labels = c("1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
                                "2010", "2015"))**
```

The new values do not appear on the x-axis. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBT9y.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(pivoteddata)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(pivoteddata, 20))`.

Comment: > summary(pivoteddata)
          country       year               value      
 Belgium      :35   Length:175         Min.   :54.50  
 France       :35   Class :character   1st Qu.:80.30  
 Italy        :35   Mode  :character   Median :86.10  
 Spain        :35                      Mean   :82.37  
 United States:35                      3rd Qu.:87.55  
 Afghanistan  : 0                      Max.   :95.50  
 (Other)      : 0

Comment: Thanks for the summary, but that's not enough to plot the data. Please post the output of the `dput` command like stated in my first comment.

Comment: > dput(head(pivoteddata, 2))
class = "factor"), year = c("X1984", "X1985"), 
value = c(NA_real_, NA
structure(list(country = structure(c(10L, 10L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", 
"Albania", "Algeria"...),  
row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Almost there! Those are only 2 values, not 20. And the beginning of the output is missing.

Comment: Apologies - I tried to upload 20, but it's far too long.

Comment: OK, that's because `country` is a factor, and `dput` will include all of its levels, even if they are not present in the selected data set. But what you have posted is enough for us to have an idea of the data structure.

Comment: > dput(head(pivoteddata, 20)) structure(list(country = structure(c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Label = c("Afghanistan" - deleted countries - "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), year = c("X1984", "X1985", "X1986", "X1987", "X1988", "X1989", "X1990", "X1991", "X1992", "X1993", "X1994", "X1995", "X1996", "X1997", "X1998", "X1999", "X2000", "X2001", "X2002", "X2003"), value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 90.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Try `pivoteddata$year <- as.numeric(sub("^X", "", pivoteddata$year))` and plot again. Also, if the x axis labels are difficult to see, maybe the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330989/rotating-and-spacing-axis-labels-in-ggplot2) can be helpful.

Comment: @Rui Barradas. Thank you. I'm sorry my comment was so poorly defined. Thank you very much for your patience with me. And thank you for answering my question! You're the best. If you post it as an answer I will accept as a solution and upvote you

Answer (score 0):

Without having your data, I would say you should use `scale_x_continuous()` instead of `scale_x_discrete()`

Answer (score 0):

You should post a reproducible example to know what `class(year)` is. Assuming that's a `factor`, try this:

```r
ggplot(pivoteddata, aes(x=year, y=value, group=country, 
                        color=country, size=10)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
                              "2010", "2015"), 
                   labels = c("1985", "1990", "1995", "2000", "2005", 
                              "2010", "2015"))
```