# stagger X-axis labels using plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, axis-labels

Using ggplot I am able to stagger the x-axis labels using the scale_x_discrete function

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(A = factor(LETTERS[1:5]), B = c(abs(rnorm(5)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=B))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

However, I wish to do the same programming in plotly within the R environment (ie. not using the ggplotly wrapper function).  Does anyone have an idea what function I should use?

Comment: See also `plotly.R` issues [#989](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/989) & [#2246](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/2246)

Answer (score 0):

To generate this type of labeling, you can use `ticktext`. However, you have to include `tickvals` for it to work. Other than the default colors, I generated a Plotly version that is extremely similar to the `ggplot` graph in your question.

```
set.seed(23)
df1 <- tibble(A = factor(LETTERS[1:5]), B = c(abs(rnorm(5))))

plot_ly(type = "bar", data = df1, x = ~A, y = ~B) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(tickmode = "array",
                      tickvals = df1$A,
                      ticktext = c("A", "\nB", "C", "\nD", "E"),
                      ticklen = 5, ticks = "outside"))
```

The `ggplot` is on the left; the `plotly` is on the right.

[image] [image]