Changing rotation, orientation and text size
I have the following code which creates a Complex Upset from a matrix with the additional orange highlight where there are three or more sets on the bars.
#where 'sets' comes from colnames() in the matrix

(upset(data,sets,
       min_size=1,
       name='Multiple Sets',
       wrap=TRUE,
       themes=upset_default_themes(text=list(element_text((family='Trebuchet MS')))),
       base_annotations = list(
         'Intersection size' = intersection_size(
           mapping=aes(fill=3Plus)
         ) +
           scale_fill_manual(values = c(
             'YES'='orange','NO'='black'
           ))
         +ylab("Count of Intersection")
         +theme(legend.position = "none")
         ),
       set_sizes=(
         upset_set_size()
         + ylab('Count of Set')
       )
       ))

The end user has requested that I increase the font size of everything to make it more readable when it is inserted into documents etc. but I cannot figure out how to do this. Can anyone please assist?
I was thinking of changing the orientation of the column labels as well so that the increased font size does not drag out over adjacent columns, but the justification is off when I use:
'Intersection size' = intersection_size(
           mapping=aes(fill=MCNFlag)
           ,text = list(angle=90)
         ) +
           scale_fill_manual(values = c(
             'YES'='orange','NO'='black'
           ))

I have tried using hjust and vjust here, but I get the error message that it is an unknown parameter. Thanks!

ggplot2 themes have a convenient base_size parameter.

How do I use that? I tried +theme(base_size=20) and got the error "Error in ggplot_add():
! Can't merge the text theme element.
Caused by error in merge_element():
! No method for merging  into <element_text>.
Run rlang::last_trace() to see where the error occurred"

No, you need to use a specific theme such as theme_bw(base_size = 20).

That works, though it is adding other elements (lines and axis numbers) which are not needed and clutter the view and it does not solve the label rotation and positioning. And advice on how to do the latter specifically? I would like them to read upward at the top of the bars

Study help("theme") and the output of print(theme_bw). Then create your own theme. Or maybe one of the other predefined themes suit your needs? See help("theme_grey"). For rotating axis labels, see one of the many posts showing that, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331400/1412059

It is not the axis label I am looking for, it is the column label.  I don't need an axis label for the column part of the chart, but I do need the labels on the columns.
